# Package Manager Console has wrong version of PowerShell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017, package-manager-console

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.7.3) on Windows 10 on two PCs, home and work.  Both have all of the latest updates applied both to the OS and to VS.

The problem is this: My work PC shows me a very wrong, very old (2.0) version of PowerShell in Package Manager Console.  My home PC shows me the correct (5.1) version corresponding to the OS version.

When I fire up PowerShell by itself, outside of Visual Studio, it shows me 5.1 on both machines.

I cannot figure out what is causing the problem with Visual Studio on one PC and not the other and I don't even know where to begin looking.  Can anyone give me any ideas?

Here's what I see on the work computer when enter the command "$PSVersionTable" in PM Console:

> PM> $PSVersionTable
>
> Name                           Value
>
> ----                           -----                                                                                                             PSVersion                      2.0
>   PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
>   BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385
>   CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
>   WSManStackVersion              2.0
>   PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
>   SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Here's what I see with the same command on my home PC, all looks well.

> PM> $PSVersionTable
>
> Name                           Value
>
> ----                           -----                                                                                                       PSVersion                      5.1.16299.492
>   PSEdition                      Desktop
>   PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
>   BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.492
>   CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
>   WSManStackVersion              3.0
>   PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
>   SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

In my investigations so far, I did come across a workaround (in the accepted answer to [this question](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/35803/help-error-the-package-manager-console-requires-po.html)) that lets me edit the devenve.config file for Visual Studio to add some package redirects.  This does fix the problem but every time I make any minor configuration change to Visual Studio, the file gets overwritten and I have to do it all over again.

Any idea where I might look to fix this?

Comment: It sounds like VS is launching powershell with `-Version 2` as an argument.

Comment: If that is the case, is there anywhere you know of where I can find/control how VS launches powershell?  Is PackageManager Console configurable in this way?  Looking at Tools >> Options >> NuGet Package Manager I can't see anything

Comment: I do not since I don't use powershell within VS, but that's the only thing that comes to mind since Windows 10 comes with v5.1 as the default (no possibility that it does *not* have it)

Comment: Yeah, 5.1 shows up fine on both machines when I just launch PS normally outside of VS .  But somewhere, somehow there has got to be some VS box I can check, some extension I can uninstall that would prevent this from happening.  Wish I could figure out what the heck it was